# How to delete a sub commit after squashing commits?

Tags: git, github

As far as I know, git squash is quite useful when there is a bunch of commits in one pull request. It can help to combine commits and then reduce the number of commits.

For example, here is what some squashed commits look like on GitHub:

```
edit readme once                        28d8d9c289665039e62d0be0f24876f096e591e2
  second edit
```

It looks like the sub commit `second edit` does not have a corresponding ref.

Is it possible to just remove the sub commit like `second edit` after squashing commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Use `fixup` instead of `squash`. It's like `squash`, but it will discard the commit messages for everything but the first commit.

### Long answer

It seems to me that this isn't a "subcommit", but instead someone accidentally kept the commit message of the second commit in the new squashed commit. By default, a squash will combine both commit messages, and it's up to you to update the message.

In this case, there is nothing you would need to remove. Just remember to change commit message as appropriate the next time you squash. You can also use `fixup` when you don't need the other message.

Comment: hmm... thanks. Just another quick question, that if i use squash, and push the commit to the remote already. one day, i find part of code in "subcommit" (second edit for example) does not correct, and want to delete them, is it possible to delete without touching "edit readme once" commit?

Comment: Git commits are immutable, so it is not possible to edit a commit (without rebasing). You can use `git revert -n` and pass it a commit ref, and it will produce changes that do the opposite of that commit without committing anything yet. Then you can edit it and remove changes you don't want and commit it to revert parts of the old squashed commit you didn't want (though this will work regardless of if the commit has been squashed or not).